# How to concatenate a return function into a SVG transform attribute using D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to get a value from a array data using the d3.js svg functionality i was able to get the X and Y value from the data array variable, now i want to get the rotation using the same approach but i am having trouble concatenating the function inside the `transform=rotate()` my code is below.

```
var spaceCircles = [    
           {x:30, y:30, r: 45  } , 
           { x: 100 , y : 100 , r: 45  }
      ];

   var svgContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
                       .attr("width", 800)
                       .attr("height", 400)
                       .style('background','#f4f4f4')
                       .style("border", "1px solid black");

        var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("rect")
                          .data(spaceCircles)
                          .enter()
                          .append("rect");

        var circleAttributes = circles
                       .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x })
                       .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y })
                       .attr("width", 80)
                       .attr("height", 20)
                 //below part is my problem
                       .attr('transform', 'rotate('+  function (d) {   return d.r }  +')');
```

> .attr('transform', 'rotate('+  function (d) {   return d.r }  +')');

Any suggestions would be great! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the whole `rotate` attribute:

```
.attr('transform', function (d){
    return 'rotate('+ d.r +')';
});
```